# Best lightweight browser for OS X 10.4.11 iBook G4

Tags: software-recommendation, youtube, powerpc, macos

I have an iBook G4 running OS X 10.4.11 and I really would like to watch youtube videos, but it is very choppy and generally impossible to watch!

I've read over this thread: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=768766 and it suggests changing the power to Best Performance, turning off hardware acceleration, and upping the Flash cache size to 10MB, all of which I have done. I'm also downloading the iBook optimized Firefox 4.0 to try that out (though that seems a little outdated, seeing as the newest version is about 20 versions newer.)

Strangely enough, my system can play DVDs at full-screen with no problem whatsoever.

Does anyone know of any good, lightweight, web browsers (or alternatively, a way that I can get Youtube working within TenFourFox 24?)

Thanks!

**EDIT**:
Just a heads up, I was able to get 240p playing fine in OmniWeb. Version 5 I believe. It had occasional lag, but generally it was good. My internet isn't good enough to play anything about 360p, so I don't go above that, but I really would like to be able to use 360p instead of 240p, if possible. I think it's the quality of the video that is causing the lag, even though DVDs play at very good quality.

I also tried using the optimized version for iBook G4, but it said that it couldn't run on my system...annoying.

Comment: Just a heads up, I was able to get 240p playing fine (occasional lag, but generally good.) My internet isn't good enough to play anything about 360p, so I don't go above that, but I really would like to be able to use 360p instead of 240p, if possible. I think it's the quality of the video that is causing the lag, even though DVDs play at very good quality.

Answer (score 3):

### [TenFourFox](http://www.floodgap.com/software/tenfourfox/)

A rewritten version of Firefox compiled to run great on older hardware.

[image: TenFourFox]

> We take the industry standard Mozilla Firefox browser and rewrite it to be compatible with Mac OS X 10.4 and 10.5, then compile it specially optimized for your G3, G4 or G5, add AltiVecTM JPEG, HTML and WebM decoding acceleration for G4 and G5 Macintoshes, and soup up JavaScript performance with our best-in-class just-in-time PowerPC script compiler. One of our four versions is just right for your particular Power Mac. And we keep it current, secure, and ready to rock.

Comment: Yeah, I have that and I'm using it now. Sadly, it doesn't support Flash. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

So, in my meandering, I managed to get 360p quality (I believe) video playing through MacTubes! Happies! I had to use the Quicktime part of the app, but I have it working! No browser required!

However, if anyone knows of any good lightweight browser, please still answer, as that was the original question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tenfourfox disables all plugins so you wont be able to watch youtube on it. Tenfourfox is good for browsing and google type uses. I recommend to use safari (check that it is the lastest version posible), omniweb or opera.

Comment: You should add a link to the software in order to improve your answer.

Comment: Fortunately, in Jan 2015 Youtube drop flash as default, and primary use HTML5 to deliver its content without requiring any plugin. - https://www.theverge.com/2015/1/27/7926001/youtube-drops-flash-for-html5-video-default

Answer (score -1):

If you use safar and have it open tabs as a developer. You can view YouTube as if it's on an iPad. Forces QuickTime instead of flash.